# How do I add to a variable in separate file using python?

Tags: python, file, csv

My situation is, I have csv file and here is its code.

```
user_file = Path(str(message.author.id) + '.cvs')
if user_file.exists():
    with open('test.csv', 'a') as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(data)
else:
    with open(user_file, 'w') as fp:
        data = [('xp', 0)]
        writer = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(data)
```

I'm wanting a csv file that keeps track of how many times they type a message so i need a way of editing the csv file and adding 1 to what it already has.  But i have no idea how to do that! please help!<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.csv:
    4

Python:

```
# Replace test.csv with the file you wish to open.     Keep "w+"
with open("test.csv", "w+") as dat:
    # Assumes the text in the file is an int
    n = int(dat.read())
    dat.write(str(n+1))
```

Result in test.csv:
    5

This way it opens the file as write and read, reads the number, then writes it back as a string. Note that `write()` will override any text in the current file, so you don't need to remove the text

P.S if that if else statement is to check the file actually exists, it's unnecessary. If you try to `open()` a file which doesn't exist, python will create it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  you are a true life saver!

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TumedSm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-package
s\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "CthuluBot.py", line 112, in on_message
    n = int(dat.read())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

How do i fix that? Im assuming this is an error on my side for sure. xD

Comment: @TumedSm make sure there is a number in the CSV file and no other text, otherwise this won't work. That error means it's either found nothing in the CSV file, or some text which isn't an integer